# Duvida Encoding Utf8 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, swift-3

Estou tendo bastante problemas com o encoding do meu aplicativo.
Tenho uma rádio online nos Estados Unidos e estou tentando um aplicativo para a mesma.
Recebo o metadata das musicas do LastFM.

```
let queryURL: String
    if useLastFM {
        queryURL = String(format: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=%@&artist=%@&track=%@&format=json", apiKey, track.artist, track.title)
    } else {

        queryURL = String(format: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=%@+%@&entity=song", track.artist, track.title)
    }

    let escapedURL = queryURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Diz o CENTOVA que envia em UTF8, mas não to conseguindo resolver isso.

Quando eu uso:

```
 @IBAction func testeS(_ sender: Any) {
    let musica = self.track.title
   print(musica)

}
```

Recebo a Saída assim por exemplo:

```
DireÃ§Ã£o do vento Part CÃ©sar Menotti
```

Já tentei de toda forma, mas assumo que não tenho completo domínio do Swift, estou estudando! Obrigado a quem leu/ajudou/colaborou com minha dúvida.

Answer (score 3):

O encoding é passado em transformações `String <=> Data`, por exemplo:

```
let string = "Codificação"

// String => Data
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)
// 13 bytes <...>

// Data => String
String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
// "Codificação"
```

O método `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)` transforma sua `String` em texto válido para `URL`:

```
string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
// "Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o"
```

O problema deve estar no momento que a propriedade `track.title` é atribuída e, como esse texto está chegando no seu app.